# What is the optimal Fourier series convergence rate estimate for $|x|$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence, approximation-theory

What is the known best estimate of the rate of convergence in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ (or maximal absolute value) of the Fourier series of $|x|,\, x\in[-1,1]$? If I look at the coefficients of the Fourier series, it is $\sim \frac1{n^2}$ so the error should be $O\big(\frac1n\big)$ where $n$ is the highest power of the partial sum of the Fourier series. Is the convergence rate higher than $\frac1n$?

Comment: Prove that $\ln(x/sin(x))$ is convex. This is incredibly simple. I don't know if it is for you. Once $f$ is convex, then $e^f$ is convex too. Again, extremely easy.

Comment: @deyore: Are you posting your comment to the wrong question?

Comment: You know to what question it refers to.

Comment: @deyore: Yes, indeed. It is obvious. I should have thought of the convexity. Thank you very much for chasing me down! :-) I would have awarded you all the points, if not for those ignorant people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convergence rate is indeed not significantly higher. If it was $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1-\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon$, then [Bernstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_(approximation_theory)) would imply that $|x|$ is in the H$\ddot{\text o}$lder space $C^{1+\epsilon}$ which it isn't.

Comment: Excellent! +1 This is **the** answer I am looking for. How did you find it? Did you already know the theorem before? Is this a very famous one within the approximation theory or functional analysis? Thank you.

Comment: It is a classic and basic result in approximation theory and has lots of extensions and equivalents in other settings (algebraic polynomials, multivariate functions, different regularity spaces,...). Btw, I remember feeling the same awe that you are describing when I first saw the theorem :)

Comment: Yes, awe indeed! Do you have any references, for proofs and applications, that touch on the "extensions and equivalences in other settings" that you mentioned? If so, would you please expand and elaborate your answer and include the reference too? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my corrected answer. Intially, I have misread the function. Of course $f(x) =|x|$ defined on $[-1,1]$ can be periodically extended as a **continuous function**. It is somesort of a 'triangle-function'.

> We are going to show that the convergence rate is **exactly** $1/n$.

First note, that
$$\widehat{f}(k) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 |x| \exp(-\pi \mathrm{i} xk) \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{ k \sin(-\pi k) + \cos(-\pi k) -1 }{k^2} = \frac{\cos( \pi k) -1}{k^2}.$$

In order to obtain a statement about the convergence rate, we rewrite the partial sums as the convolution of the function with the Dirichlet kernel. The kernel is given by
$$D_n(t):=\sum_{k=-n}^n \exp(\pi \mathrm{i} kt) = \frac{\sin(\pi(1/2+n)t)}{\sin(\pi t/2)}$$
and thus we get
$$\sum_{k=-n}^n \widehat{f}(k) e^{\pi\mathrm{i} k x} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 f(x-y) D_n(y) \, \mathrm{d} y.$$
Hence, we can write
$$f(x)-\sum_{k=-n}^n \widehat{f}(k) e^{\pi\mathrm{i} k x} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 (f(x)-f(x-y)) D_n(y) \, \mathrm{d} y $$
Using the definition of $f$, whereby we should recall that $f$ is a periodic extension, the last integral can be written as
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{\max(-1,x-1)} (|x| -|x-y-2|) D_n(y) \mathrm{d} y&+\frac{1}{2} \int_{\min(1,x+1)}^{1} (|x| -|x-y+2|) D_n(y) \mathrm{d} y \\
&+ \frac{1}{2} \int^{\min(1,x+1)}_{\max(-1,x-1)} (|x|-|x-y|) D_n(y) \mathrm{d} y \tag1
\end{align}
This formula is a bit messy, but we need to distinguish if $|x-y| \leq 1$, $x-y >1$ or $x-y < -1$. And this three terms correspond to these cases. We need to to handle all three integrals in (1) separately.

For simplicity let us assume that $x \geq 0$. In fact, the other case are similar. Note that the critical points are $x=-1,0,1$ because $f$ is not differentiable in this points. In this case, the middle-integral in (1) vanishes, because $\min(1,x+1) =1$, and if $x>0$ the first integral is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{x-1} (x-(2+y-x)) D_n(y) \mathrm{d} y.$$
If $x=0$ this integral vanishes too. The function 
$$\tag{g}g(y):=y/\sin(y \pi/2)$$ is smooth on $[-1,1]$, because we have a removable singularity in $y=0$. By partial integration, we find
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{x-1} y D_n(y) \mathrm{d}y=\mathcal{O}(1/n) \tag2$$
uniformly in $x \in [0,1]$. Of course, we can do this step in detail: By applying two times partial integration, we may show that
$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^{x-1} y D_n(y) \mathrm{d}y = g(x-1) \frac{\cos(\pi(1/2+n)(x-1))}{\pi(1+2n)} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^2)\tag{3.1}.$$
Thus, the critical part is
\begin{align}
(x-1)\int_{-1}^{x-1} D_n(y) \mathrm{d} y = (x-1)& \left. \frac{\cos(\pi (1/2+n)y)}{\pi(1/2+n)} \frac{1}{\sin(\pi y/2)} \right|_{y=-1}^{x-1} \\
& + \frac{\pi}{2} (x-1) \int_{-1}^{x-1} \frac{\cos(\pi (1/2+n)y)}{\pi(1/2+n)} \frac{\cos(\pi y/2)}{\sin(\pi y/2)^2} \mathrm{d} y \tag{3.2}
\end{align}
Note that in (3.2) the first term is of order $\mathcal{O}(1/n)$. Additionally, using $|\sin(y\pi/2)| \geq |y|$ we get that the last term is also $\mathcal{O}(1/n)$ uniformly in $x \in (0,1]$.

We can use a similar argument to show that the third term in (1) is also of order $\mathcal{O}(1/n)$. In fact, this term is equal to
$$ \tag{5} \frac{1}{2} \int_{x-1}^x y D_n(y) \mathrm{d} y + \frac{1}{2} \int_x^1 (2x-y) D_n(y) \mathrm{d} y.$$
The same argument as before (using that $g$ is smooth) shows that the critcal part is
$$\tag{6} x \int_x^1 D_n(y) \mathrm{d} y$$
and this can be handled as in the previous step.

We have already shown that the error-term is $\mathcal{O}(1/n)$ uniformly in $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Calling the error term $R_n(x)$, that is (1), we are going to show that $R_{n_k}(x) n_k \not\rightarrow 0$ for some special subsequence depending on special $x \in (0,1)$. This implies that error-term cannot be better than $\mathcal{O}(1/n)$.

We begin with adding (3.1) and the Integrands with $y$ in (5), that is
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^x y D_n(y) \mathrm{d}y - \frac{1}{2} \int_x^1 yD_n(y) \mathrm{d}y.$$
Using the same argument as in (3.1) we can easily verify that the this term is
$$g(x) \frac{\cos(\pi(1/2+n)x)}{\pi(1/2+n)} + \mathcal{O}(1/n^2).$$
In (3.2) the third term is $o(1/n)$, depending on $x \in (0,1)$ now, by the Riemann-Lebesgue-Lemma. Moreover, we do the same for (6) as in (3.2) to get
$$x\int_x^1 D_n(y) \mathrm{d} y = -g(x) \frac{\cos(\pi (1/2+n)x)}{\pi(1/2+n)} +o_x(1/n).$$
Thus, adding all together we see that
$$R_{n}(x)  = g(x-1) \frac{\cos(\pi(1/2+n)(x-1))}{\pi(1/2+n)} + o_x(1/n)$$
If we now take $x \in (0,1)$ irrational, then there exists a subsequence $(n_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\cos(\pi (1/2+n_k) (1-x)) \rightarrow 1$. Thus $R_{n_k}(x) \pi (1/2+n_k) \rightarrow g(x-1) \neq 0$. (Note that $g$ has no zeros!)

Comment: This is wrong. $f(x)$ periodically extending to $R$ **is** continuous. Your coefficient asymptotic is wrong too, since $k=j\pi$ where $j\in\mathbf Z$ makes $\sin(k)=0$, and $\hat f\sim\frac1k^2$.

Comment: Oh, you are right! In the meantime I have repaired my answer and given a complete answer to your question showing that the convergence rate is $1/n$ as supposed. Sorry for the wrong answer!

Comment: I know the technique through the Dirichlet's kernel. There are several issues with your derivation. First, this method is to show the convergence rate is $O(\frac1n)$ not $\sim\frac1n$. Second, your derivation is pretty sloppy. There is no $2$ in $|\cdot|$ in Eq. (1). Which is your "middle integral" in Eq. (1)? I do not see any integral vanishing there when $x\in(0,1)$. Eq. (2) is actually harder than Eq.(3). But you write all the derivation details of the latter while ignoring those of the former. It seems unbalanced.

Comment: This could be a good partial answer, if you carry out the derivation correctly and in appropriate details. Thank you.

Comment: I have added a complete answer showing that the convergence rate is $1/n$ and not better than this. Some details had been added, too. However, it is a bit messy and the calculations you have to do yourself.

Comment: Your proof is still too sloppy to separate the gem from the rock. You say "we can use a similar argument to show that the third term is also of order $(1/n)$." Which is the third term, as there are only two terms in Eq. (3.2)? The same question for your statement "in (3.2) the third term is $o(1/n)$". Also $|x−y±2|$ in Eq. (1) should just be |x−y|. Do you agree? You did not explicitly define $g$...

Comment: Obviously, the main equation is (1), where we have to bound the three integrals separately! The function $g$ was already defined in the text - now I have added additionally the numbering (g) in order to see the definition! No, i don't argree with your last comment: The term $|x-y\pm 2|$ is absolutley fine! For example, in the integration region $-1 \leq y \leq \max\{-1,x-1\}$ we have that $1 \leq x-y \leq 2$, so that $x-y$ lies already in the second period of $f$. By definition - as we extended $f$ as a periodic funtion - we have $f(x-y) = |x-y-2|$. The rest of the proof is fine ...

Comment: After your edit, your proof now has the shape of a proof. It is just it is too sloppy to be completely convincing. I will find some time to go through the details. I do appreciate your work.